# open() file failed (13: Permission denied) in nginx & docker & minikube

Tags: nginx, docker, file-permissions

**This only happens with docker inside minikube**
operating on host using minikube docker `eval (minikube docker-env)`

Trying to build a basic setup with Nginx serving a single file:

conf.d/example.conf

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name localhost;
  location /file.json { root /data/; }
}
```

data/file.json

```
{"a": 1}
```

Run using docker nginx image:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$(PWD)/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d":ro -v "$(PWD)/data:/data":ro -p 8085:80 nginx
```

`curl http://localhost/file.json` gives me `2017/02/01 19:07:39 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/data/file.json" failed (13: Permission denied)...`

Cannot figure out how to make this right... Help wanted!

What I've tried so far:

1. providing a custom command like `chmod -R o+x /data && ls -la data && nginx -g "daemon off;"`

   `-rwxrwx--- 1 root 1013 11 Feb  1 13:08 /data/file.json`

   chmod does not seem to work properly.
   neither chown :(

   `$ docker run -it --rm -v "$(PWD):/etc/nginx/conf.d":ro -v "$(PWD)/data:/data" -p 8085:80 nginx bash -c 'chown -R nginx:nginx /data/ && ls -la /data/ && nginx -g daemon off;"'
   total 8
   drwxrwx--- 1 root 1013  102 Feb  1 13:08 .
   drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  1 19:50 ..
   -rwxrwx--- 1 root 1013   11 Feb  1 13:08 pub_key.json`
2. setting a docker user to `nginx`
3. `chmod -R 777 data` on host

   `$ ls -la data
   drwxrwxrwx  3 antonk  staff   102 Feb  1 17:08 data
   $ docker run -it --rm -v "$(PWD):/etc/nginx/conf.d":ro -v "$(PWD)/data:/data" -p 8085:80 nginx bash -c 'ls -la /data/ && nginx -g "daemon off;"'
   total 8
   drwxrwx--- 1 root 1013  102 Feb  1 13:08 .
   drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  1 20:20 ..
   -rwxrwx--- 1 root 1013   11 Feb  1 13:08 pub_key.json`

   $ docker version
     Client:
     Version:      1.13.1-rc1
     API version:  1.23
     Go version:   go1.7.4
     Git commit:   2527cfc
     Built:        Sat Jan 28 00:43:00 2017
     OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

   Server:
     Version:      1.11.1
     API version:  1.23 (minimum version )
     Go version:   go1.5.4
     Git commit:   5604cbe
     Built:        Wed Apr 27 00:34:20 2016
     OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
     Experimental: false

   minikube version: v0.15.0

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1067

Comment: Are you running this under the /Users folder? Please include a long listing of the directory on both your host and inside the container after you ran the chmod on the host.

Comment: Yes, /Users/... on my Mac

Comment: All of the output you've provided is running the command inside a container. Where is the output from running the command on your host, without any docker command?

Comment: What does `echo $(PWD)` output?

Comment: /Users/antonk/...

Comment: Fixed by upgrading to the newer image (`minikube start --iso-url=https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.0.5.iso`). See the issue for details

Answer (score 1):

When you map directories from the host directly into your container with volume mounts like these:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v "$(PWD)/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d":ro -v "$(PWD)/data:/data":ro \
  -p 8085:80 nginx
```

The files are mounted directly in with the same uid's and file permissions you have on your host. Most likely your UID/GID on your host does not match those used inside the container. So if the files are not publicly readable on your host, they will not be readable inside the container. You can work around this with the following on your host:

```
chmod o+rx data && chmod o+r data/file.json
```

Comment: no luck both on host and docker sides
`docker run -it --rm -v "$(PWD):/etc/nginx/conf.d":ro -v "$(PWD)/data:/data" -p 8085:80 nginx bash -c 'chmod -R 777 /data/ && ls -la /data/file.json && nginx -g "daemon off;"'
-rwxrwx--- 1 root 1013 11 Feb  1 13:08 /data/file.json`
chmod does not seem to work properly

Comment: Did you actually run the command on the host? Since you mounted the volume RO, there's no way to modify it in the container.

Comment: notice `-v "$(PWD)/data:/data"` do not have `ro` flag in my comment

Comment: I totally forgot about minikube context https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube, sorry. Docker on my Mac works fine! I think this is a minikube issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah, minikube is a completely different question. I'm not sure if they even support host volumes or if they share any folders from MacOS into their embedded VM.